# Is it possible to get all authors by single query in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ManyToManyField("Author")

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField("Author")
```

I am trying to show all related authors when I visit one author detail. To do that currently I do this to achieve this:

```py
authors = []
for chapter in Author.objects.get(id=id).chapter_set.all():
    authors.append(chapter.artists.all())
```

Is there any other way to do this by djangoORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow `ManyToManyField` relationships backwards in filters, in the case of the `Author` model you should be able to use `chapter__` to access the `Chapter.author` relationship

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(chapter__author_id=id).distinct()
```